How to check if a new fuse is a suitable replacement to the blown one
I have a portable oscilloscope and I have blown its 10 A fuse, thats said, I’m having a hard time finding a similar specced fuse. The old fuse had a marking of an Dissmann HD504

Of course I filtered by amperage first, then voltage rating second, and at this point only 1 fuse is left: 0ADKC9100-BE from Bel Fuse

My main concern is the this fuse is a 'Slow-blow' fuse which I would think that for a tester I would need a fast blow one. Would this be an alright fuse as a replacement? This for the 10 A ammeter portion of my oscilloscope.

Basically, the fuse is not used to protect electronics, but to prevent fire.

@freestyle Test instruments are in a bit of special class since the user can connect them to any source he or she wants, and if the fuse does not have adequate interrupting capacity for the source it may fail to break the circuit before a lot of energy is released, possibly harming the user.

@freestyle i think it does protect electronics, because from what i know typically digital ammeters work by using a shunt resistor and excess current can burn that shunt resistor or skew its calibration. Like how I blown my fuse by accidentally shorting a 100A capable battery (BMS only kicks in at the rated 100A). Also there is what Spehro said.

@DrakeJest I'm not saying that a fuse is not needed, I'm just saying that it fundamentally does not protect electronics, it can save, but this is not its direct function. In your shunt example. Do you really think a fuse can win a shunt (if fuse will be installed for correct current)?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I generally agree with you, but even you give an example that the main goal is to save a person's life, not a device. That is, a fuse is needed to save a person's life, not to save a device. But how can it save? From direct impact with current - no, it cannot, because milliamperes are enough for impact. Prevent fire - yes, it is possible.

@freestyle In the case of a multimeter with a 10A shunt it should protect the device by keeping the traces from being blown off the circuit board, but the most important purpose is to prevent the multimeter from literally exploding in the face of a hapless user if they touch 600VAC (480VAC in the US) mains with the leads plugged in the wrong sockets.

You're right, these aren't comparable. I just when ahead and typed the five values we had for the Bel Fuse device into python, did the same for the I²t bound specified by Dissmann, and got these curves:

So, the Bel Fuse fuse is a solid 20 to 30 dB slower than the Dissmann one, on expectation, if we assume the Dissmann curve to be a typical behaviour.
It's a bit strange that you only found the slow-blow variants from Bel, though. https://www.digikey.de/short/d47dpqwn has fast-blow variants as well.
I'll let you plug in the numbers into the script yourself:
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

# Bel Fuse worst-case
datapoints={21:30*60, 27.5:80, 40:8,100:0.15}
# Bel Fuse best-case
datapoints2={15:30*60, 27.5:0.75, 40:0.15,100:0.01}

# x axis points for quadratic
x = numpy.linspace(0.9*min(datapoints2.keys()), 1.1*max(datapoints.keys()))

#plotting

f = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=100)
pyplot.plot(datapoints.keys(), 20*numpy.log10(list(datapoints.values())), label="Bel Fuse from table (worst-case values)")
pyplot.plot(datapoints2.keys(), 20*numpy.log10(list(datapoints2.values())), label="Bel Fuse from table (best-case values)")
pyplot.plot(x, [20*numpy.log10(134 / x_**2) for x_ in x], label="Dissman from I²t data")

pyplot.legend()
pyplot.xlabel("Current [A]")
pyplot.ylabel("logarithmic time [dBseconds]")

pyplot.savefig("plot2.png")


Thanks for the great graph. Looks like i have to keep looking then, if i really cant find one i might have to start compromising on lower voltages, just so that i can start using the ammeter functionality

what's wrong with the fast blow ones I linked to?

When i made the comment your edit didnt show up on my end yet, but now that i have looked at it unfortunatly the dimension does not match i need something that is close to 5mm by 20mm. Thank you for the code also by the way, i was ggoing to ask for this when i found candidates.

I don't see anything in Digikey's offerings that is comparable to the Dissmann fuse claimed performance.
The company makes high voltage fuses for EVs and multimeter fuses, maybe they have some tricks.
I can find a suitably rated 1.25" x 0.25" fuse with leads if I relax the size requirement.
Note: If you search for replacement fuses for PEAKTEC you'll find availability of 600V 5x20mm fuses, especially in Europe.

Yes that is indeed my problem also digikey and mouser don't have something comparable. 1.25" x 0.25" ( 32mm x 6.3mm) is just to big for the fuse holder, the 6.3mm might fit but the length definitly not.

There seems to be only 1 alternative also if i relax the voltage ratings to 400v : https://www.digikey.ph/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/0487010-MXP/5029353
